# firebase auth undefined class 'OAuthProvider'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement firebase auth with apple this example
https://medium.com/@karlwhiteprivate/flutter-firebase-sign-in-with-apple-c99967df142f

but I faced this issue

> undefined class 'OAuthProvider'.

in this snippet

```
OAuthProvider oAuthProvider =
    new OAuthProvider(providerId: "apple.com");
final AuthCredential credential = oAuthProvider.getCredential(
  idToken:
      String.fromCharCodes(appleIdCredential.identityToken),
  accessToken:
      String.fromCharCodes(appleIdCredential.authorizationCode),
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OAuthProvider` provider was recently added to `firebase_auth`. You need to upgrade the `firebase_auth` version in your project to the following:

```
dependencies:
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3+1
```

Then do `flutter pub get` to be able to use the package.

Answer (score 1):

I think right now everyone is dealing with this sign in with apple mandatory.

This two dependencies will make it easier.

```
dependencies:
    firebase_auth: ^0.15.3+1 
    apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0
```